# frama-c stops propagation: "Assertion got status invalid"

Tags: c, frama-c, program-slicing

I want to slice the file `test.c` for all assertions.

`test.c` looks as follows:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   float r;
   float g;
   float b;
} Color;

typedef struct {
   int k;
   Color* colors;
} Colors;

void foo(int* a, int k, Colors *colors)
{
    int b=0;   
    colors->colors = (Color*) malloc(k*sizeof(Color));
    //@ assert (colors == NULL);
    if (colors==NULL)
        return;

    colors->k = k;
    int c=10;
    *a=8;
    //@ assert(*a>b);
}
```

I run frama-c with the following command:

`frama-c -slice-assert @all -main foo test.c -then-on 'Slicing export' -print -ocode slice.c`

The resulting `slice.c` looks as follows:

```c
/* Generated by Frama-C */
typedef unsigned int size_t;
struct __anonstruct_Color_1 {
   float r ;
   float g ;
   float b ;
};
typedef struct __anonstruct_Color_1 Color;
struct __anonstruct_Colors_2 {
   int k ;
   Color *colors ;
};
typedef struct __anonstruct_Colors_2 Colors;
/*@ ghost extern int __fc_heap_status __attribute__((__FRAMA_C_MODEL__)); */

/*@
axiomatic dynamic_allocation {
  predicate is_allocable{L}(size_t n) 
    reads __fc_heap_status;

  }
 */
void foo(int *a, Colors *colors)
{
  int b;
  /*@ assert colors ≡ (Colors *)((void *)0); */ ;
  return;
}
```

Looking at the sliced function `foo`, it seems as if the processing was somehow incomplete. The frama-c output tells me:

```
test.c:19:[kernel] warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(&colors->colors);
test.c:20:[value] Assertion got status invalid (stopping propagation).
```

What is "status invalid" supposed to mean? Why does it stop propagating here and why does it work, when I change the first assertion to `//@ assert (colors != NULL);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Slicing plug-in relies on information computed by Value Analysis. During its run, Value Analysis attempts to evaluate any ACSL annotation present on the branches it explores. This is in particular the case for `assert colors == NULL;` in your example, which is indeed deemed to be invalid.

Why is that? First, we can note that `colors` is a formal argument of the main entry point. By default, Value Analysis will create an initial state in which such pointer is either `NULL` or a pointer to a block of two elements (see [Value's user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-value-analysis.pdf) for more information about the default initial state of the analysis and how it can be customized if needed). Thus it would seem that the assertion would just remove the second possibility and keep `NULL` as the only possibility for `colors`.

However, there is one other thing the function is doing with `colors` before reaching the `assert`: it assigns something in `colors->colors`. For this assignment to be valid, `colors` needs to point to a valid memory location. Hence the warning you see on line 19 (seemingly emitted by the kernel for historical reasons, but in reality emitted by Value), materialized by the generation of another assertion, `\valid(&colors->colors)`, that you can see if you launch `frama-c-gui` with your options.

After having emitted an alarm, Value attempts to reduce its internal state according to it, as a concrete execution can only go further (without venturing in Undefined Behavior land) if it validates the given condition. In our case, this means removing `NULL` for the set of possible values for `colors`. Hence, when we encounter the assertion, we only have one possibility for `colors`, and since it does not match the assertion, the status is invalid and propagation is stopped: no concrete execution can attain this point and validate the assertion.

**UPDATE** If you change the first assertion to `//@ assert (colors != NULL);`, Value analysis will find it is valid, since, as said above, reaching the point where the assertion is evaluated can only be done with a valid `colors` pointer because of the `colors->colors` in the previous instruction. Thus Value proceeds with the analysis, and the Slicing is done on a program that terminates normally, leading to the expected result.

Regarding your comment, an ACSL annotation is valid if during any concrete execution of the program which passes through the annotation, it evaluates to true, and invalid otherwise (and execution is supposed to stop in case the annotation evaluates to false). In practice, it is often not possible (at least not in a reasonable amount of time and/or memory) to perform all such evaluations, hence the unknown status, meaning that the plugin can't decide. Note that in any case, the status emitted by a given plugin depends on the configuration of this plugin. For instance for Value, the chosen entry point and initial configuration have an impact on the validity status of the annotations encountered by Value during its abstract execution. More precisely, each time the abstract execution reaches an annotation, the status is computed as follows:

- if the annotation is true for all the concrete states represented by the current abstract state, valid status is emitted.
- if the annotation is false for all such concrete states, invalid status is emitted, and abstract execution stops for this branch (since no concrete execution would go past the annotation).
- otherwise the status is unknown: Value has no way to know whether the concrete states for which the annotation evaluates to false can really happen in practice or are just an artefact of the approximations made so far. However, it attempts to reduce its abstract state to make it represent as few invalid states as possible (e.g. if you have `/*@ assert 0<= x <= 10;*/` and `x` is known to be in the interval `[3; 17]`, Value will use `[3; 10]` for the interval of `x` after the assertion).

Comment: It was a typo, I meant `//@ assert (colors != NULL);` (edited my question)

Apparently, I think I kind of misunderstood the meaning of the ACSL assertions...Since I don't think I understood this a 100%, could you please define "status valid", "status invalid" and "status unknown" in a few words explaining under which curcumstances, which of these is the case in general?

Comment: I've tried to explain that, but this might require a whole new question.